# Javascript inner function memory leak?

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, xmlhttprequest

I've been working with Javascript recently but I'm not actually very proficient with it.  I'm trying to track down what looks to be a memory leak, since my Memory Usage seems to steadily increase.  One idea I have for what might be causing this is the use of inner functions.  I use inner functions when dealing with XMLHTTPRequests (and other related objects) and these requests get created every few seconds.  I feel like perhaps I'm not closing it properly or something.  So here's some code for one of the inner functions, if someone could tell me if this is the problem and how to fix it that would be great.  (This is in the context of IE, I do not know and cannot find out if it happens in other browsers).

```
    me.request.open("GET", url, true);
    me.request.onreadystatechange = onReadyStateChange;
    me.request.send(); 

    function onReadyStateChange() {
        if (4 == me.request.readyState) {
            if (me.request.status == 200) {
                var results = me.request.responseText;
                var resultsString = me.request.responseText.toString();
                me.stringOperation(resultsString);
                me.request.abort();
                me.request = null;
            } else {
                me.request.abort();
                me.request = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
function noop() {}
```

And then in `onReadyStateChange`, after `me.request = null`, `me.request.onreadystatechange = noop`.

This removes a cyclic reference between `me`, and `onReadyStateChange` that crosses the JS object / host object barrier.

Comment: But ... the XMLHttpRequest object isn't really a DOM thing, is it?  Or are you saying that IE has the same problem with those that it does with actual DOM elements? (I ask out of ignorance.)

Comment: @Pointy He probably meant JS object (built-in object) / browser object (host object). Some people refer to all host objects as DOM objects. (in a browser environment, at least)

Comment: @Šime Vidas well in this case my curiosity is whether IE has the same problems with these objects as with DOM elements. I suppose it's not at all hard to believe that it might.

Comment: Another question, why would I change me.onreadystatechange?  It's me.request.onreadystatechange that gets assigned...

Comment: @Pointy From my understanding, IE generally has problems with cyclic references. But I'm far from an expert on this issue (I just block IE on my pages, and that solves my IE issues, as far as I am concerned `:)`)

Comment: @user Try: `me.request.onreadystatechange = null; me.request = null;`

Comment: @Šime, Setting to `null` fails on at least one browser version, but I can't recall which right now.

Comment: @Pointy, yes, that is what I meant.  Thanks.  Edited to use your language.

Comment: @Mike Oh yes, I meant this of course: `me.request.onreadystatechange = noop; me.request = null;` I think, one has to first overwrite the onreadystatechange property, and then set the xhr object to null. At least, that makes most sense to me.

Comment: @Šime, Ah, I was missing a ".request" in my answer which was probably the source of a lot of confusion.  Thanks for pointing that out.